# copying of data validation to the entire column

Tags: excel

I have used the following data validation for enabling/disabling a cell depending upon the condition of the previous cell. But now, I want to copy the same condition to the whole column which I tried doing using `copy>paste special>validation` but this is not working. Please somebody help me with this.

```
B2=IF($A$2="Ocean","",$D$11:$D$12)
```

Comment: Just paste the formula which creates the validation

Comment: ya i did the same but it is not getting pasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *'but this is not working'* mean that you are able to copy validation but not getting expected result than you probably need not anchor row number of column 'A'

Try: `=IF($A2="Ocean","",D$11:D$12)`

Comment: welcome and next time be sure to frame questions in details so as to explain the problem clearly.

Comment: i have tried this code for making a cell mandatory, it is working good for a cell but i want to apply the same for the entire column and 8 more columns which are mandatory...

     Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim oldTarget As Range
     Dim Target As Range
     Set oldTarget = Target
     If oldTarget.Address = "$B$1" Then
     If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Hi"
     End If
     End Sub

please help

Comment: If your range of 8 columns is from B to I, you can use this to check if target address is in range: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B:$I")) is Nothing Then....`. Also, I am not able to understand why are you declaring 'Target' again. `Dim Target As Range` is not required as it may cause unexpected scoping error

Comment: acutlly my aim is now to use in validation for whole A1 and B1 columns, can you suggest me how to do that?